# Yup: validate at most one field

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, yup

Using Yup can I validate that **at most "n of m"** fields have been set? For example: if I have a *string field*, a *boolean field* and and *array field*, can I set Yup to **check that one and only one of these fields isn't equal to its default value**?

```
yup.object(
  field1: yup.string(),
  field2: yup.boolean(),
  field3: yup.array(),
);
```

---

Or with a more complex example (*which may warrant its own question*), if `field0` is `true`, then one and only one amongst `field1`, `field2` and `field3` is different than its default value, if `field0` is `false` than each of the other three must be equal to its default.

```
yup.object(
  field0: yup.boolean(),
  field1: yup.string(),
  field2: yup.bool(),
  field3: yup.array(),
);
```